# Windows Server 2008 System Specific Remote

Tags: windows, iis

I have a server which runs Windows Server 2008 R2 Standard. I have admin rights and I can login through Remote Desktop Connection and access the server.

I wanted to create an account so that my office staff can access (restricted access) and only from office systems. I do not want access from any other location.

Is it possible ?

Thanks,

GR

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to lock down and secure the RDP services of a particular machine. As with most local services and GPO settings Windows is quite good at making it easy to tailor permissions based on user(s), computer(s) and by group(s).

First off I would personally add RDP permissions on a per user basis, rather than giving staff members one central login to use. There are several reasons for this, mostly down to ease of use and system security.

In the "System Properties" of the Windows Server, I assume you've ticked the box to allow a RDP connection to the server. - Just under that there's a checkbox you should tick in order to only allow connections with NLA *(Network Level Authentication)*. Proceed to "Select Users" and choose the staff you wish to give RDP permissions too.

I'm going to assume that your RDP connection is working as you've stated that you're able to connect, we'll leave local RDP GPO settings and initial Windows Firewall configuration, please leave a comment if you'd like me to include it.

In the Windows Firewall for the server on the exceptions tab, edit the settings for Remote Desktop Connection. Click "Change Scope" and tick the box that says "My Nntwork (subnet) only".

This will only allow RDP connections from local machines within the servers subnet (office machines) and connections from the users you specified earlier on (Office staff).

As for the restricted access part, short of making a new local limited user on the server there's not much you can do to protect everything.

I hope this clears it up for you.

Comment: Thanks for your help Sam. From what I understand, currently my setting in server to RDP connection is allow regardless of any version of windows. I will change it to allow connections with NLA. Since this is a VPS server, the domain profile firewall is on but public and private firewall is off. Plus I couldn't find change scope option. Actually I only need to give permission to 1 staff only. So should I create a limited user a/c and then add in rdp.

Comment: Yeh that would be your best option if it's for one staff member only.

Comment: Sam, the VPS server is like any virtual private server and is not physically in my network. So will changing scope in windows firewall work?? As mentioned above I didnt find that option in the first place.

Comment: Even within a VPS environment the machine(server) should accept individual firewall rules. They'll be server side rules set by the VPS provider but this will be for the network in general. - If you run in to problems explain what you want to do to the host, it won't be the first time they've had the request.

Comment: See image attached: http://s10.postimg.org/rjimcniyh/tmp.png . I need to create a standard user account and modify Remote Desktop inbound rule. Am I right? The window you see in the image, do I have to put ip there. But how to specify that the rule is for a particular user.

Comment: If it's for one user then don't bother with the firewall rules, that was more for multiple users to add extra security. - Create the limited account and give them permission to RDP to the server. - That should suffice.

Comment: Since I did not want that guy (whose standard account I created) to access RDC from any location except work, I restricted it by IP. Unfortunately IP at my workplace is dynamic and that became a problem. Is there a way to solve this?